# Configuring WebAPI for Forms Authentication

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, security, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I'm working with webApi and trying to implement forms auth.  My application is using simpleMembership.  For some reason my controllers are reverting to my windows credentials to check and see if a request is authenticated, when it should just be using simpleMembership against my app's database:

[image]

I've disabled windows and anonymous auth in the app and in my applicationhost config file... what else needs to be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your API Controllers, when you need to enforce authentication (non-public controllers or actions) you need to use the

```
[Authorize]
```

... attribute at either the controllers or action level, according to your needs.
Please note this is the attribute implemented on System.Web.Http not the one in System.Web.Mvc

The one you use for Api Controllers checks the Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated instead of HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated as System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute does.

You need to populate this Principal on each request, usually by using a DelegatingHandler, which is explained on this link:

http://www.piotrwalat.net/basic-http-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-using-message-handlers/

In the link above, the author is using Basic HTTP Authentication, which transmit the credentials in plain text on each request; but you can implement your own authentication strategy in order to populate the Principal, which is all you need.

Comment: Thank you Raciel.  I have most methods decorated with [Authorize], but login/register should be accessible by all users, so I'm planning on leaving those methods undecorated.  Does that sound right?  And - do you have an example of how I can populate the principal?  Is that just manually setting the Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity within the Handler (one line of code)?

Comment: Sure, public methods should not wear [Authorize].
The link I provided in my answer shows you how to populate the Principal, check line# 16.
You want to do this in a DelegatingHandler and either use something basic as Basic HTTP Authentication or something more complicated, if needed.
For Basic Http Auth you can check this out: http://leastprivilege.com/2012/10/23/mixing-mvc-forms-authentication-and-web-api-basic-authentication/